# fs.writeFile works with path, but do not work with fd argument

Tags: node.js

```
fs.open('./test.txt',(err, fd) => {
  fs.writeFile(fd, 'proba', (err) => {
    console.log(err)
 })
```

})

In this example when I use `fd` as first argument in fs.writeFile I got error:

```
[Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write] {
   errno: -9,
  code: 'EBADF',
  syscall: 'write'
 }
```

But if I instand of `fd` put path of file (`'./test.txt'`) everything works fine.

What is happening, why I can't use file descriptor in this situation.
As I found in documentation it should be possible to use it on this way with file descriptor parameter.

Comment: The documentation [literally calls this situation out](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_using_fs_writefile_with_file_descriptors)? The real question is "why are you using `open` with `writeFile`"? Either use the low level `open` with the low level `write`, or use the single higher level `writeFile`.

Comment: I'm just learning Node.js, and trying to understand it.

When I used it on this way, my process of thinking was:
The `fs.open(path, callback)` method is used to allocate a new file descriptor, and it is in first argument of callback.
Then I tried to use that fd to write to file (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_using_fs_writefile_with_file_descriptors)

If you can  explain me, what is wrong in this process of thinking and this approuch, It would be helpful for me?
Please if you can, give me extensive explanation.

Comment: I already linked to the part of the docs that give you exactly that explanation: did you click on it, and read it? As for where the reasoning failed: it went wrong when you started with "I need a file handle". You don't. For any of the normal functions, you tell Node what the file path is, it does the rest.

Comment: In documentation which you sent: they told that fs.writeFile() is alomst idetntical to fs.write(). And they explain difference, but that is only what I found in documentation

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans one more question, please.

How do you know which functions are low level and which ones are high level?
And do we need to always use it separately?

I suppose that low level functions, are those which have similar function with same name in Linux. Is that only way to distinguish them?

Comment: Almost all `fs` functions are higher level: you give a path, and Node does the rest. `writeFile`, `readFile`, etc. all just need you to tell it which file you're talking about. You are _not_ responsible for creating file handles. Ignore prior knowledge of other programming languages or even kernel calls: the API is [full of functions that take paths, not file handles](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), which makes development a _lot_ easier (and Node is really good at file I/O).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to run your code on node.js 14.4.0 on Windows 10, I get an EPERM error.  I don't see the same error you get.  I can fix that error, by passing in the `open` mode to `fs.open()` so it doesn't default to readonly.  Here's the code that worked for me:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.open('test.txt', 'a+', (err, fd) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);  
  } else {
    fs.writeFile(fd, Buffer.from('proba'), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  }
});
```

I would agree with the other commentor that it really doesn't make sense to use `fs.writeFile()` with `fs.open()` as `fs.write()` is more appropriate and a lot more clear what the code actually does.

Comment: Adding `a+` flag to `fs.open()` method solved my issue. Thank you @jfriend00 .


Now I just wondering why it is works, when I put path as first parameter in `fs.writeFile(path)` instead of `file descriptor` even without `a+` parameter.


Why I used it on this why? 
It is because I'm learning `node.js` and I tried to explore how to use `file descriptor` which we create with `fs.open()` method.

Why you get different error? It is cause I'm  working on mac os.

Comment: @PredragDavidovic - Because `fs.writeFile()` with a pathname uses it's own default access mode for `fs.open()` internally, probably `"w"`.   Yes, the different error is probably because of a different OS.  If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you  some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass flag for writing  or reading as second argument in fs.open() method.
For e.g, we can pass w for writing, r for reading or r+ for reading and writing both.

Try this  code:

```
fs.open('./test.txt', 'w', (err, fd) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    fs.write(fd, 'proba', (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("File created!");
    })
})
```

Hope this will work.